# How to get exact query into logs with graphql?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I want to retrieve each query/Mutation and put them in logs :

```
....
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  resolvers: [query, mutation, tables],
  debug: DEBUG,
  context: params => () => {
    return f.context(params);
  },
....
```

and in my context function I have :

```
function context(params) {
   ....
   let query = params.req.body.query;
   ...
}
```

the problem is : params.req.body.query is equals to  all the queries in the body and not the one who is executed.

for example, if in graphiQL I have :

```
 mutation a {
   createElement(...) {
     ...
   }
}

mutation b {
 updateElement(...) {
    ...
  }
}

mutation c {
  deleteElement(...)
}
```

regardless of the mutation used, I would receive exactly the same result in my log.

So my question is : is it possible to get only and only the executed query ?

Comment: You could do this with a [graphql middleware](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-middleware/tree/master/examples/logging). If you want to use it with apollo server have a look at [this](https://github.com/maticzav/graphql-shield/blob/master/examples/with-apollo-server-lambda/handler.js)